# How to validate only specific schema from a dataframe

Tags: python, testing, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am trying to test specific schemas from a dataframe. In the data frame, there are some columns that have no value or null value.

```
     def test_column_names(self):
            schema=StructType([StructField("column 1", StringType(), True),
            StructField("column 2", StringType(), True),
            StructField("column 3", StringType(), True),
            StructField("column 4", StringType(), True),

        assert schema in df.columns``


The df.columns has more than 1000 schemas. I wanted to verify only the above schemas exist in the df.columns and assert that. I have tried ``assert schema in df.columns``. But getting AssertionError: unit test failures:
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a very cool implementation, still does the job :)

```
%python

for sccols in schema:
    for dfcols in df.schema.fields:
        if (sccols.name == dfcols.name):
            if (sccols.dataType == dfcols.dataType):
                assert True
            else:
                assert False
        else:
            pass
```